# npm multer is not uploading files

Tags: node.js, npm, multer

I am using multer to upload files on nodejs application. On my local and on my first server it's was working perfectly but in the second server files just not going to they folder. File name is generating normally. I have try to change folders rights for file host folder and for multer application.
I have added some controlling functions to see what is happening at upload.
onFileUploadComplete: show normaly message like file is there.
onError: not called.

Comment: I think we would need more logs etc to see, but have you checked file permissions as a starting point?

Comment: After few hours i have found the solution, was stupid mistake. Location in my local windows pc and my linux server was working, but in new server wasn't. I just pass full path to folder and it works.

Comment: Logs was clear, all good, file uploading normally. I guess it saved somewhere else, couldn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you answered you own question! Write it as an answer here! 
It actually saved me, but I didn't read it the first time because I was looking for correct answers.

**I also entered the entire path and it worked**